# Having multiple tabs open if multiple checkboxes clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a chrome extension where a user has the choice to check as many boxes as they want that will load different webpages corresponding to which selection(s) they picked.

so far my html code for the checkboxes is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="google" 
id="google" >
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="yahoo" 
id="yahoo" >
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="msn" 
id="msn" >
```

and the JS I tried to use was this:

```
function redirect()
{ 
if(document.getElementById("google").checked == true) . 
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';

else if(document.getElementById("yahoo").checked==true)
window.location.href = 'https://www.yahoo.com;

else if(document.getElementById("msn").checked == true) 
window.location.href = 'https://www.msn.com;'
}
```

the sites load correctly if I picked one option but wont load all the sites to each checkbox checked if more than one was checked. How can I change the code so that if multiple checkboxes were checked, each of the sites of that checkbox would load?

Comment: with `window.location.href` you are just replacing old link with new ones, try launching in new tabs instead, why not just use `<a target="_blank" href="...">` instead?

Comment: Why use else if you want to check multiple condition.

Comment: You have a wrong use of `if`-statements. The script will only progress if your first condition is true. `if cond1 = true then "say hi" else "jump"` <-- This says if condition one is true then it will say hi. If it's not then it will jump ;)

Comment: I figured it had something to do with that. Thank you, it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (document.getElementById("google").checked == true)
    window.open('https://www.google.com');
else if (document.getElementById("yahoo").checked == true)
    window.open('https://www.yahoo.com');
else if (document.getElementById("msn").checked == true)
    window.open('https://www.msn.com');
```